# Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffers' and fussy rendering on Qt5.1.1

Tags: qt5

I have install qt5 on my window machine.to see it is working i just create new simple Qt Quick 2 UI project that contain one main view file. when i run it the application run well except this issues on my application output pane

- ***getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebuffer'***
- ***getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferOES'***
- ***getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferARB'***

and fussy rendering on the application output window(qmlscene)

Comment: Did you install the OpenGL build on a machine without OpenGL drivers?

Comment: I don't know the laptop is not mine. how can i know OpenGL drivers is installed? and its version too?

Comment: @peppe thanks for your direction, after some googling i able to  update my intel HD graphics on machine then everything goes well.

Answer (score 3):

fussy rendering problems are usually due to out date of graphics card not able to support OpenGL. so if you encounter such kind of issues in Qt5 while working with qt Quick 2 it can be solved the problem by updating your graphics card